# How to store double array data into string in php?

Tags: php

I have data in double array in php. Now I need to store that array data into string. How can I do that in php? I am new to php. Please help me in this regard.

Array is as follows:

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 100 [type] => test1 [count] => 8 [count2] => 8) 
   [1] => Array ( [id] => 103 [type2] => test2[count2] => 3 [count3] => 3 ))
```

Comment: Is "double array" == php 2d array or something else ?

Comment: can you please paste array here?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Double array means what? two array or 2d array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode()` to convert an array into a string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php